Error in Pytorch - Runtime error :one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation
I am trying to implement a Neural ODE in pytorch and I am getting the following error. I am new to Pytorch and I am not able to understand where the error is coming from.
The error is :

one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.DoubleTensor [100, 3]] is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

This is my code snippet below.
class NeuralODE(nn.Module):
      def __init__(self,x1,x2):
          super(NeuralODE,self).__init__()
          self.x1 = x1
          self.x2 = x2
          l = 100
          self.f = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(3,l),nn.Tanh(),nn.Linear(l,1))
      
      def forward(self,t,x):
          ifunc   = self.x1
          t_numpy = np.array([t.item()]) if t.dim() == 0 else t.detach().numpy()
          i       = torch.DoubleTensor([ifunc(t_numpy)]).reshape(-1,1)
          x2    = (self.x2).clone().reshape(-1,1)

          #dy/dt 
          C = 5
          dy_dt = (-1/C)*i
          S       = x[0,:].clone().reshape(-1,1) 
          T       = x[1,:].clone().reshape(-1,1) 

          
          i_S_T = torch.cat((i,S,T),dim=1)

          # dp/dt
          C1    = 0.0015397895
          C 2   = 0.020306583

          Q = self.f(i_S_T) # Finding Q through the neural network
          dp_dt = (-C1*(T-x1))+(C2*Q)

          return torch.cat((dy_dt,dp_dt),dim=0)

I tried to find the inplace operations and I couldn't. I tried using torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True). But that also didn't help.
